# Quickly navigate path with evil-mode's ex commands?

Tags: helm, evil, find-file

I am new to Emacs. I like how I can easily navigate to a file via `helm-mode-find-file` in `helm`.

*Is there any way to combine any variant of this (`helm` or otherwise) with `evil`'s `ex` commands (eg, `:e`, `:sp`, etc.)?*  Or do I really have to type the full path by hand every time I am trying to open a file from the hard disk?